# Redux dependency graph

Tags: reactjs, react-native, redux

I have been working with redux for some time now.
I noticed that when developing a feature or fixing a bug, I almost always produced some side effects on components that relied on the same state values.
I am wondering if there's a static code analysis tool that would generate a graph of dependencies between reducers, actions and components (I'm using redux-connect to link state and actions to components).
This would be a great tool to anticipate what would be affected by changes in the state life cycle.

Anyone knows whether such a tool exists?

Answer (score 0):

There are some kinds of libraries for this:

1. [devtools-extension](https://github.com/zalmoxisus/redux-devtools-extension)
2. [Redux DevTools Chart Monitor](https://github.com/reduxjs/redux-devtools-chart-monitor)

that are the ones i know and use.

Comment: Thanks for you answer. Actually I'm not looking for a tool that shows the current state the app is running.
I would like to see which react components uses which state or trigger which actions and which actions affects which element in the state. This would require a tool that does some static code analysis.

Comment: with the Devtool-extension and the official devtools you can archive exactly this